# How to apply theme_menu_tree to only the top <ul> menu

Tags: theming, routes

I am using the following function in the template.php (drupal 7) to override the original menu output. However, the  tags in all levels are also affected. I wonder how to only apply it to the top/first  tag? Please advise. Thanks!

```
function THEMENAME_menu_tree__MAIN_MENU($variables) {
  return '<ul id="myid" class="menu myclass">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: have not tried it but you could try this solution https://gist.github.com/3201854

Comment: thanks a lot for your guidance. it helped me a lot in my problem but do you know how can I change the #theme function of specific menu items.

Comment: @Mehrdad201 this is a different matter: https://www.drupal.org/node/988694

Answer (score 2):

In order to theme the top level `ul` tag only:

```
function THEMENAME_menu_tree__menu_top_menu(&$variables) {
 return '<ul class="menu myclass">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

You have to put this piece of code in your custom theme's `template.php` file and replace `THEMENAME` with your theme's name.

Comment: Although it's an old question, felt like posting this for the sake of completeness.

Comment: thanks. I have tested out but it's not working for me. no classes added. Nothing happen. Does it work for you ?

Comment: Updated answer. Yes I have tested it and works.

Comment: It is not working for me also.

Comment: this came from https://www.drupal.org/node/988694