# Trying to update taxonomy menu item with hook_taxonomy_menu_update

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm having issues getting this to function to work, if I understand correctly this hook fires after saving or creating a taxonomy term.

I am also unable to use dpm($item) as nothing is rendered

```
function form_alter_taxonomy_menu_update(&$item) {
    $item['options']['attributes']['class'] = 'myClass';
    return $item;
}
```

Can anyone spot what I have done wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you're just adding a class, I wouldn't rely on a hook from the taxonomy menu contributed module at all. Do it at the theme level [like this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/139392/34502).

Comment: Thanks.I need to make the class the value of a field from my term, is this still possible with the method you are suggesting?

Comment: You could use Views to generate the menu instead of taxonomy menu, then use replacement patterns to put the value of a field within the class.

Comment: Yeh I've wondered this, just I have never built a hierarchical structure before, I guess now is the time to learn!

Comment: You might be interested in this too: https://www.drupal.org/node/988694